# Typescript: Property “” does not exist on type never

Tags: typescript

I am trying to access property of an object inside the same object with "this" keyword.

Example

```
const obj = {
  a: "1",
  b: "2",
  c: this.b,
};
```

But when I do so, TypeScript gives the error:

> Property "" does not exist on type never.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: An object can not self reference like that.

Comment: Use a class or a function to define your object, or assign `c` as a getter.

Comment: An object in JavaScript/typescript doesn't mean the same thing as an object in object oriented languages. `this` will refer to the class or function instance that the code is in